# Unable to set android camera parameter in Samsung Glaxy s3 Neo

Tags: android, camera

Before setting parameter i get all supported parameter by the device and try to set the minimum dimension, but the problem is that it is working fine with other devices but in case of Samsung glaxy s3 neo its not setting picture size parameter.

```
parameters.setPictureSize(size.width, size.height)
```

can anyone help me. Thanks